# Clustering application master error

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I follow [this link's](http://chad.ill.ac/post/35967173942/easy-ejabberd-clustering-guide-mnesia-mysql) steps, but after this command in terminal:
`easy_cluster:join('ejabberd@master.domain.com')`, I got error message from slave log file like this:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 2013-12-16 20:08:45 ===
    application: mnesia
    exited: stopped
    type: permanent

=ERROR REPORT==== 2013-12-16 20:08:45 ===
    application_master: shutdown_error
    ejabberd_app: {prep_stop,[[]]}
    error_info: {badarg,
                    [{ets,lookup,[local_config,listen],[]},
                     {ejabberd_config,get_local_option,1,
                         [{file,"ejabberd_config.erl"},{line,590}]},
                     {ejabberd_listener,stop_listeners,0,
                         [{file,"ejabberd_listener.erl"},{line,360}]},
                     {ejabberd_app,prep_stop,1,
                         [{file,"ejabberd_app.erl"},{line,81}]},
                     {application_master,prep_stop,2,
                         [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,373}]},
                     {application_master,loop_it,4,
                         [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,349}]}]}
```

Comment: ets:lookup should only throw a badarg if the table it's checking doesn't exist, which would suggest that the ejabberd app is not started in the terminal you're using.

Comment: would you suggesst me ejabberd clustering setup i spent lot of time in ejabberd clustering but still i didn't get it.